# Getting errors: framework not found FirebaseCore

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods

I keep getting the following error

```
ld: framework not found FirebaseCore
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

here is the pod file

```
platform :ios, '11.4'

target 'Myproject' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'FirebaseStorageCache'
end
```

I have been struggling with this issue for days now. Request your help.

Comment: Did you opened the ".xcworkspace" and not the ".xcodeproj"? When you installed the pods, not issue on the command?

Comment: Does removing use_modular_headers! make a difference?

Comment: Yes, I am using xcworkspace...I tried removing use_modular_headers!  too. I get a different error. Here is the error I get "[!] The 'Pods-project' target has transitive dependencies that include static frameworks: (FirebaseAuth, FirebaseCore, FirebaseDatabase, and FirebaseStorage)"

Comment: have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

close xcode
pod reintegrate
pod install
open xcode
cmd+k
built